# How to get content value in Xunit when result returned in IActionResult type

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit, asp.net-core-webapi

I have a unit test project using Xunit and the method we are testing returns `IActionResult`.

I saw some people suggest using "NegotiatedContentResult" to get the content of the `IActionResult` but that doesn't work in Xunit.

So I wonder how to get the content value of an `IActionResult` in Xunit?

Test code example is provided below:

```
public void GetTest()
{
    var getTest = new ResourcesController(mockDb);

    var result = getTest.Get("1");

    //Here I want to convert the result to my model called Resource and
    //compare the attribute Description like below.
    Resource r = ?? //to get the content value of the IActionResult

    Assert.Equal("test", r.Description);
}
```

Does anyone know how to do this in XUnit?

Answer (score 52, accepted):

Depends on what you expect returned. From previous example you used an action like this.

```
[HttpGet("{id}")]
public IActionResult Get(string id) {        
    var r = unitOfWork.Resources.Get(id);

    unitOfWork.Complete();

    Models.Resource result = ConvertResourceFromCoreToApi(r);

    if (result == null) {
        return NotFound();
    } else {
        return Ok(result);
    }        
}
```

That method will either return a `OkObjectResult` or a `NotFoundResult`. If the expectation of the method under test is for it to return `Ok()` then you need to cast the result in the test to what you expect and then do your assertions on that

```
public void GetTest_Given_Id_Should_Return_OkObjectResult_With_Resource() {
    //Arrange
    var expected = "test";
    var controller = new ResourcesController(mockDb);

    //Act
    var actionResult = controller.Get("1");

    //Assert
    var okObjectResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;
    Assert.NotNull(okObjectResult);

    var model = okObjectResult.Value as Models.Resource;
    Assert.NotNull(model);

    var actual = model.Description;
    Assert.Equal(expected, actual);
}
```

Comment: what about if returning dynamic object in ok, for example: Ok(new {token="", expiration=DateTime.Now.AddHours(1)};

Comment: Saved my day.  Just to add that I got a warning from RSharper stating "Assert.Equal should be Assert.AreEqual"

Comment: It seems that there's something more to what's returned. I'm returning *IActionResult<List<Donkey>>* but when I softly cast the result to *List<Donkey>* I get *null* because it's got included properties and the object seems to be of the type *QueryableIncludeable* or something like that. Never seen that class before...

Comment: @KonradViltersten That is an invalid cast. Check this article in docs https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/web-api/action-return-types?view=aspnetcore-2.2#actionresultt-type

Comment: Sorry, I can't see it in the text. Possibly due to my confusion. I noticed that when I have included something and return an array of such objects that have each one its own inclusion, I had to use that class. Would you be able to elaborate what you meant that the case was invalid, please?

Answer (score 0):

The above solution gives a CS0039 in .NET7.0

Possible solution:

```
// Arrange
var expected = "test";
var controller = new ResourcesController(mockDb);

// Act
var actionResult = controller.Get("1");

// Assert
actionResult.Should().NotBeNull();
actionResult.Result.Should().BeOfType<OkObjectResult>();

var model = (actionResult.Result as OkObjectResult)!.Value as string;
model.Should().NotBeNull();
model.Should().BeEquivalentTo(expected);
```