# Get value from IActionResult

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-mvc, .net-core, asp.net-core-mvc

I have Controller whit some endpoints `Task<IActionResult> MyCustomEndpoint` which is returning `return Ok(CustomDataType)`. Returned datas are in JSON fromat.

Now I want to call that Endpoint from other Controller like `var resp = myController.MyCustomEndpoint`, where resp becomes `IActionResult`. The problem is that `resp` now doesn't return only datas anymore, but all of those fields as seen on image.

[image]

My question is, how to access and return only `Value` field, because `resp.Value` is not working.

Thanks for help.

Comment: Take a look at this https://stackoverflow.com/q/39378873/2521893

Comment: For `Task<IActionResult`, try `            var result = await Endpoint1() as ObjectResult;
            var model = result.Value;
`

Answer (score 1):

You have to convert to `as ObjectResult`

```
public async Task GetFormSummary_ItShouldReturnSingleForm_NotNull()
{

    var formId = new Guid("5EF685E7-1167-4226-7F5E-08D9009544A3");
   
    var mockFormService = new Mock<IFormService>();

    mockFormService.Setup(x =>  x.GetAsync(formId).Result)
        .Returns(GetTestForm());

    // Inject
    var formController = new FormController(_logger, mockFormService.Object);

    // Act
    var result = (await formController.GetAsync(formId)) as ObjectResult;

    // Assert
     Assert.IsAssignableFrom<FormViewModel>(result.Value);

}
```