# In XUnit how to do parsing on IActionResult you receive

Tags: c#, unit-testing, asp.net-core, xunit

How do I parse the `IActionResult` I received in my XUnit Test.

I have tried the below and getting error in the line (returning *null*)

```
var okObjectResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;
```

Controller Class

```
public IActionResult Details(int id)
{
    var pie = _pieRepository.GetPieById(id);

    if(pie==null)
    {
        return NotFound();
    }
    else
    {
        return View(pie);
    }          
}
```

XUnit Test Case

```
[Fact]
public async void DetailsTest()
{
    MockPieRepository _data = new MockPieRepository();
    int _id = 1;
    string desc = "Selenium Pie";
    var homecontroller = new HomeController(_data);

    IActionResult actionResult = homecontroller.Details(_id);
    var okObjectResult = actionResult as OkObjectResult;

    Assert.NotNull(okObjectResult);

    var model = okObjectResult.Value as Pie;

    Assert.NotNull(model);         
    Assert.Equal(1, model.Id);
    Assert.Equal(desc, model.ShortDescription);
}
```

I have referred the code from the below post and still no luck "[How to get content value in Xunit when result returned in IActionResult type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378873/how-to-get-content-value-in-xunit-when-result-returned-in-iactionresult-type)"

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to get content value in Xunit when result returned in IActionResult type](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39378873/how-to-get-content-value-in-xunit-when-result-returned-in-iactionresult-type)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`OkObjectResult` usually returned by API controllers. In your particular case controller returns `ViewResult` type.

```
var actionResult = homecontroller.Details(_id);
var viewResult = actionResult as ViewResult;
var actualPie = viewResult.ViewData.Model as Pie;

Assert.NotNull(model);         
Assert.Equal(1, model.Id);
Assert.Equal(desc, model.ShortDescription);
```

[Test controller logic in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/mvc/controllers/testing?view=aspnetcore-2.1)